# SSL issue installing bootstrap gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bundle-install

I added the bootstrap gem in the Gemfile and when I try to run ***bundle install***. It shows following error!

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Nir>cd c:\Sites\FrogBlog

c:\Sites\FrogBlog>bundle install

Fetching source index from https://rails-assets.org/
Retrying fetcher due to error (2/4): Bundler::Fetcher::CertificateFailureError C
ould not verify the SSL certificate for https://rails-assets.org/.
There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most like
ly your system doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For inf
ormation about OpenSSL certificates, see [...]

c:\Sites\FrogBlog>
```

Comment: Please describe what do you want?

Comment: i want to install bundle for bootstrap or simply i want to use bootstrap for my blog!!

Answer (score 1):

This an issue with railsinstaler on windows, you may fix it using this steps !!

https://gist.github.com/fnichol/867550

---

### Edited

---

Download:

> cacert.pem

From

[curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem](http://cacert.pem%20direct%20link%20download)

Save that file to !

> C:\Path_to_RailsInstaller_directory\cacert.pem

or

> D:Path_to_RailsInstaller_directory\cacert.pem

Now make ruby aware of your certificate authority bundle by setting SSL_CERT_FILE.

To set this in your current `command prompt session` run as `Administrator`, type:

> set SSL_CERT_FILE=C:\Path_to_RailsInstaller_directory\cacert.pem

Comment: Let me know if that help you !

Comment: done but how do i add it to control panel. No Idea!!

Comment: Sorry but it said cacert.pm couldn't be downloaded